How do I allow reference arn of an httpApi lambda
I have the following test serverless.yml:
service: test1
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
             - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
          Resource:
            - Fn::GetAtt: [ api, Arn ]

functions:
  api:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get
  api2:
    handler: index.handler2
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /api2
          method: get

Deploying this gives the following error:
$ serverless deploy --stage dev --aws-profile default

Deploying test1 to stage dev (us-east-1)

✖ Stack test1-dev failed to deploy (68s)
Environment: darwin, node 20.12.2, framework 3.38.0, plugin 7.2.3, SDK 4.5.1
Credentials: Local, "default" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource api

api lambda function needs to invoke the second api2 lambda function and therefore needs InvokeFunction permission.
